# Assistance with joining two tables - not sure which joins to use

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am currently trying to bump up an application export against our enterprise HR listing to identify any current employees in the application that have been terminated (that will come from HR).

**Table 1 -** Application Listing. Contains Emp_name and Emp_ID

**Table 2 -** HR Listing. Contains Emp_name, Emp_ID, Termination_Date (important).

Do you know what code I need to end up with a column added into Table 1 with each employee's respective termination date? If NULL, they are still employed, if there's a date populated, that is our observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be this simple, unless there are other conditions you haven't discussed.

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.Termation_Date  --list out columns instead of * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.Emp_ID = table2_EmpID
WHERE table2.termination_Date IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: For the first line, what would replace the * for table1? I have tried running this and I'm getting "The multi-part identifier could not be bound", which I assume is because I'm running the script as

SELECT table1, table2.term_dt
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.Emp_ID = table2_EmpID
WHERE table2.termination_Date IS NOT NULL

Comment: The * just refers to all columns in table1. I agree with Robert's query, assuming table2 contains all employees, but if table2 does not contain all the employees in table1, I'd change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN to return all table1 records with matching table2 records. INNER will only return where the empid is in both tables.

Comment: Got it. Table 1 had 15,000 rows, table 2 had 100k+. The resulting table from that pull is 236 rows.. does this mean that there are 236 employees in table 1 that have a filled in termination_dt in table 2?

Comment: Yes.  And @riekertv is right, the INNER JOIN assumes that table1 is a complete list.

Comment: Yes, assuming there's only one empid record per person in table2. If there are multiple records for an empid in table2 you'll have to extend the query, e.g. if people are appointed on contract basis, and every appointment has it's own table2 record with a termination date, then the query above might not show the latest record, only every record with a matching empid with a termination date.

Comment: Got it, ty. INNER and LEFT gave the same results - 236 roles. Thank you everyone!